# Android Studio - Kotlin - getDrawable or getResource is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to place an image from internal storage into the background of a button. There are no error messages. I can open the storage on the emulated device and select and image, but it doesn't get placed/inserted into the button background. I am using Android 4.1 and using API Level 30 (Q) / Android 11. I am coding in **Kotlin**.

The Log says the photo is selected.

The code in question is this:

**RegisterActivity.kt --partial--**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        
        // proceed and check what the selected image was...
        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Photo was selected")

        val uri = data.data
        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri)

        val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
        select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
        select_photo_button_register.text = ""

    }
}
```

**RegisterActivity.kt --FULL--**

```
package <censored>.kotlinmessenger

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register.*


class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

        this.supportActionBar?.displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar)
        //getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

        register_button_register.setOnClickListener {
            performRegister()
        }

        already_have_account_textView.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Trying to show login activity.")

            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        select_photo_button_register.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Try to show photo selector")


            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }
    }



    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

            // proceed and check what the selected image was...
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Photo was selected")

            val uri = data.data
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri)

            val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
            select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
            select_photo_button_register.text = ""

        }
    }

    private fun performRegister() {
        val email = email_editText_register.text.toString()
        val password = password_editText_register.text.toString()

        if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please check email/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Email: $email")
        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Password: $password")

        //Firebase Auth
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

                // else if successful
                val uid = it.result?.user?.uid
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Successfully created user with uid: $uid")

                println("Email: $email\n Password: $password\n UID: $uid")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("Main", "Failed to create user: ${it.message}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create user: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
    }
}
```

**activity_register.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#86B400"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_editText_register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/select_photo_button_register" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_editText_register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/username_editText_register"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username_editText_register"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username_editText_register" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_editText_register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email_editText_register"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/email_editText_register"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_editText_register"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register_button_register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:text="Register"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password_editText_register"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/password_editText_register"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_editText_register" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/already_have_account_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Do you already have an account?"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/register_button_register"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/register_button_register"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/register_button_register" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/select_photo_button_register"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_select_photo"
        android:text="Select photo"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:backgroundTint="bitmapDrawable"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/username_editText_register"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RegisterActivity with External Storage permission**

```
package <censroed>.kotlinmessenger

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.ImageDecoder
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register.*
import java.util.*


class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

        register_button_register.setOnClickListener {
            performRegister()
        }

        already_have_account_textView.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Trying to show login activity.")

            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        select_photo_button_register.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Try to show photo selector")
            val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0)

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }
    }
    var selectedPhotoUri: Uri? = null
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@RegisterActivity,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this@RegisterActivity,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@RegisterActivity,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@RegisterActivity,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
            }
        }
        selectedPhotoUri = data?.data
//        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri!!)
//        val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
////        select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(BitmapDrawable(this.resources, bitmap))
//        select_photo_button_register.background = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)

//        try {
//            selectedPhotoUri?.let {{
//                    val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri!!)
//                    val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
//
//                }
//                select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(BitmapDrawable(this.resources, bitmap))
//
//            }
//        } catch (e: Exception) {
//            e.printStackTrace()
//        }


//        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){
//            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Photo was selected")
//
//            selectedPhotoUri = data.data
//            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
//            val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
//            select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
//        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            1 -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@RegisterActivity,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ===
                                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


                        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri!!)
                        val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
//        select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(BitmapDrawable(this.resources, bitmap))
                        select_photo_button_register.background = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }

    private fun performRegister() {
        val email = email_editText_register.text.toString()
        val password = password_editText_register.text.toString()

        if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please check email/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Email: $email")
        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Password: $password")

        //Firebase Auth
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

                // else if successful
                val uid = it.result?.user?.uid
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Successfully created user with uid: $uid")

                uploadImageToFirebase()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Failed to create user: ${it.message}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create user: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
    }

    private fun uploadImageToFirebase() {
        if (selectedPhotoUri == null) return

        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")

        ref.putFile(selectedPhotoUri!!).addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Sucessfully uploaded image: ${it.metadata?.path}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, Where did you call them? It's not in your code.

Comment: @Omkar76, it's Kotlin not Java. The `startActivityForResult` function starts the `onActivityResult` function.

Comment: I was asking where did you call getDrawable() and getResources(). They are not called  in your provide code.

Comment: @Omkar76 My understanding is that it's part of the button `select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)`

Comment: I've tried using [the code here](https://devofandroid.blogspot.com/2018/09/pick-image-from-gallery-android-studio_15.html). The permissions are OK though.

I think I might just change the button to an ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this since MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap() is depreceated.

```
try {
            uri?.let {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        this.contentResolver,
                        uri
                    )
                } else {
                    val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, uri)
                    val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                }
                select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Comment: I changed the code just to this, just to try and test it, but it still isn't working.

     `selectedPhotoUri = data?.data`
        `val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri!!)`
       `val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)`
  `select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(BitmapDrawable(this.resources, bitmap))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Replace these two lines:

```
val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
select_photo_button_register.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
```

with this:

```
select_photo_button_register.background = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
```

Comment: That didn't work either. I added "RegisterActivity with External Storage permission" with my question as I thought it might be a permissions issue.

Comment: try changing the Button to an ImageButton.

Comment: I changed it to and ImageView and put a TextView over it. See my own answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I changed the `Button` to an `ImageView` and added a `TextView` over it. I am using `Picasso` to insert it into the `ImageView`.

The `onActivityResult` deals with inserting the image.

[Permissions code obtained from here](https://devofandroid.blogspot.com/2018/09/pick-image-from-gallery-android-studio_15.html)

```
package <censored>.kotlinmessenger

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register.*



class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

        register_button_register.setOnClickListener {
            performRegister()
        }

        already_have_account_textView.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Trying to show login activity.")

            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        //BUTTON CLICK
        select_photo_imageView_register.setOnClickListener {
            //check runtime permission
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
                ) {
                    //permission denied
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    //show popup to request runtime permission
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_CODE)
                } else {
                    //permission already granted
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    pickImageFromGallery()
                }
            } else {
                //system OS is < Marshmallow
                pickImageFromGallery()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        //Intent to pick image
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
    }

    companion object {
        //image pick code
        private val IMAGE_PICK_CODE = 1000

        //Permission code
        private val PERMISSION_CODE = 1001
    }

    //handle requested permission result
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    //permission from popup granted
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission from popup granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    pickImageFromGallery()
                } else {
                    //permission from popup denied
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission from popup denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //handle result of picked image
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && data != null) {

            Picasso.get()
                .load(data.data)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(select_photo_imageView_register)

            select_photo_textView_register.text = ""
        }
    }


    private fun performRegister() {
        val email = email_editText_register.text.toString()
        val password = password_editText_register.text.toString()

        if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please check email/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Email: $email")
        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Password: $password")

        //Firebase Auth
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

                // else if successful
                val uid = it.result?.user?.uid
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Successfully created user with uid: $uid")

//                    uploadImageToFirebase()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Failed to create user: ${it.message}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create user: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
    }

}
```